# DC Motor residual voltage suppression

Tags: dc-motor

I fitted two 12 V DC cooling fans in my car that turn ON and OFF when the coolant temperature is above a certain threshold.

When the fans turn OFF, the inertia of the fans slowing down generates a residual voltage that slowly goes to 0 V within 3-5 seconds.

I would like to get rid of this residual voltage in the rest of the circuit of my car.

For instance, when I switch OFF the car while the fans are running, the car keeps running for a couple of seconds as although the ignition is OFF, there is enough residual voltage to keep the car's engine running. If I switch OFF the ignition while the fans are OFF, the car switches OFF instantly.

Another example is the dashboard indication light for the cooling fans; it slowly dims to OFF when the fans are switched OFF, instead of just extinguishing in a fraction of a second.

I was thinking of fitting a diode on the positive wire to the fans to prevent back voltage from the fans to the rest of the car. Would that work or are there any other solutions commonly used?

Each fan is drawing about 7 A current at 12 V when running.

[image]

**Edit following comments :**

Here is the actual configuration of my car as I just went through the wiring. I have an illuminated switch on the dash that allows to manually turn ON the fans (regardless of the command of the EFC) and it illuminates whenever the fans are powered (either manually via the switch, or automatically via the EFC). The switch was left open whenever the reported problem above happened as it is just fitted as a safety feature in case the EFC fails.

[image]

Comment: Can you explain how the residual fan voltage can get to other circuits given that the relay contact in series with the fan must go open circuit and leave the fan totally isolated from anything else.

Comment: @Andyaka The fan probably keeps the relay coil powered as long as it spins.

Comment: My question is directed at the OP.

Comment: Yes I believe what @Klas-Kenny is saying is correct.

Comment: It can't be correct as per your diagram.

Comment: For a shot period after the 12V supply is removed, the turning fans provides enough voltage to keep the relay coil energized, thus keeping the relay contact closed. Once that voltage dissipates, the relay contact then opens and isolates the fans. I agree that in that situation, there should be a threshold under which the power suddenly goes OFF when the relay opens, which is not what I see on the dash fan light (steadily dimming down). Unless the voltage required by the relay coil to close the contact is very low. I'll double check my wiring anyhow.

Comment: @Fredovsky you said this: `When the fans turn OFF, the inertia of the fans slowing down generates a residual voltage that slowly goes to 0 V within 3-5 seconds.` - so, if the fans are turned off, the relay must be turned off and hence nothing the fans produce in terms of residual voltage is going anywhere. How can what you observe and the diagram be compatible?

Comment: @Andyaka I think what he is suggesting is that the "+12 volt supply" in his diagram is switched by the ignition.  If the relay is already energized and the ignition is then switched off,  the fans generate power to the fan controller which is keeping the relay energized and also supplying power to keep the engine running.

Comment: I'm directing my question at the OP so that he can fix his question up.

Comment: Edit added containing the actual wiring diagram of the system. Not sure if the switch and LED shown would change anything to the solutions offered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the best solution is to power the fan directly from the battery (preferably through a fuse), instead of from the ignition.

If you don't want the fan to ever be on when the ignition is off, just power the fan controller and relay coil from ignition.

Like this:
[image: Connection diagram]

Answer (score 0):

> I was thinking of fitting a diode on the positive wire to the fans to prevent back voltage from the fans to the rest of the car. Would that work ...

I bet it works, even if it seems a little overkill (big diode even if inexpensive), but powering the fan (and only the fan) directly from the battery would be a cleaner solution.

Comment: Diode would totally work.  OP --- keep in mind the fan probably will spin alot longer as it won't be able to dump its energy.

Comment: @KyleB: you are true, but the same happens using a relay contact (open contact behave as a reversed diode). To stop the fan earlier one could deploy a SPDT contact and short-circuit the fan to the ground, perhaps through a resistor, but this seems even more an overkill. Moreover, many cars keep fan on even after the driver has turned them off and has exited...